# Python - NumPy array_split adds a dminesion

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, split

I am trying to split a data set into 3 parts and I am having issues because the matrices are not getting the dimensions I wish.

First of all, I know this method is ridiculously inadequate because it is splitting the dataset into 3 equal parts and it should be like that. 
Secondly, my major concern now is the fact that `numpy.array_split()` is adding a dimension to the arrays.

Code:

```
train, test, cv = np.array_split(data[np.random.shuffle(data)], 3, axis = 1) 

train_inputs = train[:,: -1]
test_inputs = test[:,: -1]
cv_inputs = cv[:,: -1]

train_outputs = train[:, -1]
test_outputs = test[:, -1]
cv_outputs = cv[:, -1]

print "Train Inputs Matrix" + str(train_inputs.shape) + "\n"
print "Test inputs Matrix " + str(test_inputs.shape) + "\n"
print "CV Inputs Matrix " + str(cv_inputs.shape) + "\n"
print "Train Outputs Matrix " + str(train_outputs.shape) + "\n"
print "Test Outputs Matrix " + str(test_outputs.shape) + "\n" 
print "CV Outputs Matrix " + str(cv_outputs.shape) + "\n"
print train_inputs.ndim, train_outputs.ndim, test_inputs.ndim,     test_outputs.ndim, cv_inputs.ndim, cv_outputs.ndim
```

All that, will output to the console as follows:

```
Train Inputs Matrix(1, 94935, 31)

Test inputs Matrix (1, 94935, 31)

CV Inputs Matrix (1, 94934, 31)

Train Outputs Matrix (1, 31)

Test Outputs Matrix (1, 31)

CV Outputs Matrix (1, 31)

3 2 3 2 3 2
```

The goal is to split the data set into three separate arrays, keep the original's shape, `(x, 31)` for later calculations. Then inputs will drop the last column and outputs will keep only the last column.

The strange behavior is that `array_split` is adding a dimension to the newer array. Both inputs and outputs are wrong nevertheless since outputs are keeping only the first row and not the last column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the shape of `data`?

Comment: That's the problem here. The original set is a 283034x31 array. Not a 3-dimensional array

Comment: The syntax `data[np.random.shuffle(data)]` is odd. `np.random.shuffle(data)` returns `None` but shuffles `data` in place. `data[None]` is just `data`. It would be clearer to do the shuffle on a previous line. edit: actually, `data[None]` is what's adding the extra dimension, as hpaulj said below.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the shuffle:

```
In [661]: data = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [662]: np.random.shuffle(data)
In [663]: data[np.random.shuffle(data)].shape
Out[663]: (1, 3, 4)
```

`shuffle` operates in place, and returns `None`.

```
data[None]
```

adds a new dimension at the start.  So `split` gets a (1,283034,31) which it splits 3 ways on axis=1 (as instructed).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will test shuffling out of this part instead. I will mark as solved when tested and if this does the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Wanted to say this stopped adding dimensions to the new matrices. Now a new problem to solve :'D